# `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails I just installed rails on MacOS Sierra from scratch using the following commands:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.29.1 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
$ gem install rails bundler
$ bundler -v
Bundler version 1.14.5
```

But rails throws this error:

```
$ rails -v
bin/rails:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadError)
    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

This is my PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten the same issue when i putted some gems to project folder to local connect and this gems was with git repos too. So i just removed .git folders from this gems and put theirs to project folder again. It was origin of same issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add rails gem to your project. Or you can do gem install rails

Answer (score 0):

I  could fix same error by:

```
bundle install
```

After running into the same issue with:

```
Ruby27/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands/server (LoadError)
```